# How to append a <td> in for loop using replaceWith in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append every  tag in my table inside for loop, but the loop and **replaceWith** is not working.

How to iterate the loop for each of  and **replacewith** or append to the target ?

```
for ( z = 0; z < json[x].category[y].item.length; z++ ) {
    html += '<td id="'+ json[x].category[y].item[z].idCat +'">';
    html += '<div class="new-value">'+ json[x].category[y].item[z].value +'</div>';
    html += '</td>';
}   
$('table tr td.new').replaceWith(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
count = 0;
for ( z = 0; z < json[x].category[y].item.length; z++ ) {
    count++;
    var html = ''; //define html variable first
    html += '<td id="'+ json[x].category[y].item[z].idCat +'">';
    html += '<div class="new-value">'+ json[x].category[y].item[z].value +'</div>';
    html += '</td>';
    $('table tr td.new:eq("'+count+'")').html(html); // use .html()
}
```

Comment: `var html = ''` should placed at the beginning of the loop;

Comment: Thanks ,now work, you need only to put counter outside for loop. count = 0; inside for put count++; and instead of :eq("'+z+'") i write .eq(count) and work fine for me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As you check from below code, it works okay, no problem.

```js
var html = '';
for ( z = 0; z < 3; z++ ) {
    html += '<td id="tdnew_' + z + '">';
    html += '<div class="new-value">NEW-'+ z +'</div>';
    html += '</td>';
}   
$('table tr td.new').replaceWith(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border="1"><tr>
<td>OLD-9</td>
<td>OLD-8</td>
<td class="new">OLD7</td>
<td class="new">OLD8</td>
</tr></table>
```

So I suspect that there might be 2 reasons.

**Case 1**

Your javascript code is executed before `<table>` is not there yet, thus jQuery selector `$('table tr td.new')` actually points nothing.

Simple you can add following code before `replaceWitdh()` code line, to see if really td.new is existing there when the script is run:

```
alert($('table tr td.new').length)
```

If it alerts 0, means, table is not there yet when script is running.

**Case 2**

Your json might include some invalid chars, which makes your code not working, and this case you will see some error console I believe.

Comment: thanks, the table exist and the loop append all td of the loop for every single td.new. Your solution is like the my, but not work.